# redis rpush multple values not support with php dynamically

Tags: php, redis

Redis supports multiple value in rpush which works well if i put as normally.
But it does not works dynamically.
Below i had tried in php.

```
$ids= array(1587,1588,1589,1590);
$all_comma_sperated=implode(",",$ids);
$redisClient->rPush('mylist', $all_comma_sperated);
```

Working code

```
$redisClient->rPush('mylist', 1587,1588,1589,1590);
```

It goes as a string.

```
mylist 1587, 1588, 1589, 1590
```

I do not want to loop one by one.
I am using phpredis for this.

Comment: you should be using [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

Comment: @bansi, could you elaborate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call like `$redisClient->rPush('mylist', $all_comma_sperated);` it is actually 2 parameters passed. you can call functions with variable parameters with [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) like the following.

```
$ids= array(1587,1588,1589,1590);
call_user_func_array( array($redisClient, "rPush"), 
                      array_merge(array('mylist'), $ids)
                    );
```

Comment: It works thanks, Can there be any other alternatives ?

Comment: i don't know of any other alternatives, unless you can modify method `rPush` to accept array also as second parameter.

Comment: This is a case where accepting an array makes really sense at API level. Because in Redis you can't use an array as a single element, because elements are just strings, the client side API can be overloaded without drawbacks.

Comment: @Nick someVariadicCommand(Array(...,..,..,..)) will always be a valid form compared to someVariadicCommand("a","b","c","d") because in the second form single elements should not be arrays: sets are composed of simple strings, not nested arrays.